# Cannot format usb/sd card

Tags: usb, 22.04, sd-card

I tried every single solution I fount on the forum, but still no luck.

I've got two microSD cards and one usb dongle, which I installed Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi on, that suddenly stopped working.
I tried to format the media on Ubuntu, Windows11 and MacOS but still they can't be formatted to any filesystem.

I tried to deleted partitions with GParted, but they took no effect.
Gdisk tells me there is a corrupted GPT, tried to write a blank one but no effect.
I tried to zero the media with dd, but still no effect.
I tried to clean the media with diskpart, it didn't work.

Every single solution previously proposed to a problem similar to mine I found, had no effect.
All the files on the media are still readable, but I cannot delete them, if I mount the media on a Ubuntu pc.

As you could imagine, I'm totally unexpert: I don't know which data to post (and how) to let you identify better the problem I'm experiencing.
Could anyone give me some help? For the fist media I thought it was an hardware failure, now the odds are quite low.

Thank you!
Deiv

Comment: Thank you @karel for your fast reply but no, it doesn't. I'm not getting any error until the last command: `mkfs.vfat -n "USB-32" /dev/sdc1` which give me in response `mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdc1: Permission denied`.

Comment: This is a hardware issue. I have some SDcards behaving like this. Internally broken pin?

Comment: Thank you @Marco, I thought so: but it looks so weird to me that 3 media out of 3 (different media and different manufacturers) had the same problem, in less than one month. It shouldn't be a defective pin issue of the Raspberry Pi, because the problem occurs on different usb ports, different sd card readers and different laptops. Thank you for your suggestion: if I'm not getting any other solution, the only thing I can do is to blame my bad luck :)

Comment: "INTERNAL" pin. Most probably a pin under the cover. If you are experienced in soldering, you can try to resolder the chip with hot-air (of course only USB-Memory-Stick) . The cheaper, the less solder they use, which makes it unreliable.

Comment: No, I'm not experienced at all, so I could consider them lost. BTW, it happend with a >60 € Lexar sd card, ~30 € Samsung sd card and a cheap usb-memory stick (<20 €)

Comment: Depending on the location there might still be  warranty on the card.

Comment: Thank you very much Marco for you assistance!